# Saving User Information and retrieving it

Tags: android, save, userinfo

I've been searching for a while now and not getting what i want specifically. I am creating an app in android studio which does a specific calculation, allows the user to add additional information, save and retrieve it.

Here is the idea:

The app has two buttons on the main activity named Start Project and open Project.

Start project takes you to another activity to perform a calculation. That activity has a button to the bottom which says next page and takes you to another activity where the calculation is forwarded using Intent and allows you to input certain user information and then there's an option to save.

1. How do you save that information in such a way where it can be retrieved in a list form by a reference name and number using the Open Project button on the main activity page?

Comment: sometimes you search for persistent storage in android.  But probably you'll need to learn how to do SQLITE for the listings and such.

Comment: i looked at sqlite and most tutorials im seeing is not doing specifically what i want when it comes to retrieving the data saved...i want the data to be attached to an id and when i click the id the information saved would show up